# Visual Studio custom build tool doesn't rebuild from scratch

Tags: visual-studio, build, settings

I have a generally question about "custom build tool" tab in settings.

I already used this feature and like it. But this time the result is not what I expected :/

I try to automatically convert a Performance Monitor manifest file (.man) to a corresponding .h and .rc file (ctrpp.exe). But this should not matter, just about the principle.

After I assign the custom step to the .man file, it is possible to compile the file in context menu. The build tool also recognize a modification and builds the output files again. Also the output files were deleted at rebuild.

But that's my problem.

Manual compile and inkremental build works fine, but why the files wasn't build automaticall after a first check out or at rebuild?? I expected that compiler forces a build, if it no output files found.

As result, the compiler don't find the corresponding header file in my files.

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/ide/specifying-custom-build-tools?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DDE-DE%26k%3Dk(VC.Project.VCCustomBuildTool.Outputs)%26rd%3Dtrue) (in German) describes when the update is triggered. Can I force to generate the output files?